# yii framework, how to implement union sql

Tags: php, yii

i am trying to do something like this on yii actionAdmin()

```
select * from car where carbrand = 'bmw' limit 1
union
select * from car where carbrand = 'mercedez'
```

i cannot find anything to do with union on CDbCriteria

Is there any other way?

Answer (score 3):

U can try to merge criteria with another one 
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria#mergeWith-detail 
or u can use DAO and CDbCommand http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCommand#union-detail.