# How create query with union two select in Yii?

Tags: php, mysql, yii

There is a table "Apartments". Here is a need to create a query in Yii. How to do it?

SQL query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM {{apartments}} 
WHERE agent_id = 4 
UNION 
SELECT * 
FROM {{apartments}} 
WHERE agent_id != 4
```

In my cintroller

```
$arrSql[] = 'SELECT * FROM {{apartments}} WHERE agent_id=:agent_id';
$arrSql[] = 'SELECT * FROM {{apartments}} WHERE agent_id!=:agent_id';
$data = Apartments::model()->findAllBySql(implode(' UNION ', $arrSql), array(
    ':agent_id' => Yii::app()->user->id,
    ':status' => Apartments::STATUS_REMOVED
));

$dataProvider = new CArrayDataProvider($data);
```

But not work pagination and filter in my widget CGridList.

Comment: You query is same as `SELECT DISTINCT * FROM Apartments;`, No?

Comment: possible duplicate of [yii framework, how to implement union sql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12127908/yii-framework-how-to-implement-union-sql)

Comment: What you want? you doing SELECT * 
FROM {{apartments}}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As i know, you can use the `CDbCommand` like this:

```
$apartments2 = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
    ->select("*")
    ->from('apartments')
    ->where('agent_id!=:agent_id', array(':agent_id'=>4))
    ->getText();

$apartments = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
    ->select("*")
    ->from('apartments')
    ->where('agent_id=:agent_id', array(':agent_id'=>4))
    ->union($apartments2)
    ->queryRow();
```

you can find your result in the `$apartments` as an array.

**EDIT:**

if you want to use a CActiveDataProvider, you need to use [CSqlDataProvider](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CSqlDataProvider):

```
$sql='SELECT * 
FROM {{apartments}} 
WHERE agent_id = 4 
UNION 
SELECT * 
FROM {{apartments}} 
WHERE agent_id != 4';

$dataProvider=new CSqlDataProvider($sql, array(
    'totalItemCount'=>$count,
    'sort'=>array(
        'attributes'=>array(
             'agent_id', //and all other atributes with withc you want to sort
        ),
    ),
    'pagination'=>array(
        'pageSize'=>10,
    ),
));
```

Comment: Good approach, but how i can implement it with CActiveDataProvider and CDbCriteria for my widget CGridList?

Answer (score -4):

Its very simple

```
  (SELECT *
   FROM {{apartments}}
   WHERE `agent_id` = '4')
UNION ALL
  (SELECT *
   FROM {{apartments}}
   WHERE `agent_id` <> '4')
```

Let me know if that worked for you..

Comment: A good quality answer should have more explanation. Please explain your solution with comments. Thanks.